# how works async/await under the hood in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is generators under the hood of async/await in Javascript? I read that in many web pages but i can't find it in documentation of EcmaScript and MDN. And what is really under the hood of async/await conception in EcmaScript

Comment: It's native implementation. Does not need to be generators or anything else specific. It's technically syntactic sugar over promises but doesn't need to even transform the code into promises to work. Again, it's native implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As @VLAZ said, it is native implementation. It is some kind of syntactic sugar over promises.
MDN says that:

> async/await is built on top of promises, so it's compatible with all the features offered by promises.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#awaiting_a_promise.all